# CSV generation in PHP Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I have the PHP output, which is in table form, and I want that output in CSV format. How can I get that using PHP Smarty?

Comment: by 'table form', I take it you mean HTML table, not a database table?

Comment: Not sure whether you need Smarty for this. CSV is essentially `fieldvalue;fieldvalue;fieldvalue;fieldvalue`

Comment: Yes,its not a database table.I am getting o/p as html table and then i need that o/p in csv using smarty.

Comment: Please help me out, I am new to php.

Answer (score 0):

You should parse that PHP output with an xml parser. Use something like:

```
$phpOutput = ... ; //this is the output containing only the table
$xml = simplexml_load_string($phpOutput);
$csvOutput = "";
foreach ($xml->tr as $rows)
{
   $cells = array();
   foreach ($rows->td as $cell)
   {
      $cells[] = (string)$cell;
   }
   $csvOutput .= implode(",",$cells)."\r\n";
}

$smarty->assign("csv",$csvOutput);
```

Of course you must be careful and close every tag if you don't want to get warnings.

Comment: Thanks for your response,but i want to know that whether i can have a link to html o/p i.e export to csv so it can generate that o/p in csv.

Comment: This is not a problem, you have to access that page with a separate request and before outputing anything add some headers which will force the browser to show you the save file dialog. See more on http://php.net/header